# Error running '__rvm_make -j4'

Tags: ruby

Estoy intentando instalar ruby versión 2.7.1 en WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) con Ubuntu 22.04 mediante rvm, ejecutando
`rvm istall 2.7.1`
pero me sale lo siguiente:

```
rvm install 2.7.1
ruby-2.7.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.7.1 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/22.04/x86_64/ruby-2.7.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.7.1 - #downloading ruby-2.7.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.7.1 - #extracting ruby-2.7.1 to /usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.7.1 - please wait
ruby-2.7.1 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.7.1 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.7.1 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /usr/share/rvm/log/1675786910_ruby-2.7.1/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Cuando abro el .log me aparece lo siguiente:

```
+__rvm_make:0> make -j4
        BASERUBY = echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -shared
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable -std=gnu99  -fPIC
        XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -fexcess-precision=standard -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
        CPPFLAGS =
        DLDFLAGS = -Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.2.7  -fstack-protector-strong
        SOLIBS = -lz -lpthread -lrt -lrt -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
        LANG = C.UTF-8
 LC_ALL =
        LC_CTYPE =
        MFLAGS = -j4 --jobserver-auth=4,5
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Y un montón de líneas más.

No se a qué se deba este error, necesito instalar ruby 2.7.1

Comment: Bueno, en ese monton de lineas más es donde debe estar el error, de hecho busca la palabra "error" y algo saldrá. Si no, sube el log a un pastebin y agrega el link a tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente esto lo soluciona

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

y luego

```
rvm install 2.7.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/rvm/usr
```

si no te funciona puedes intentar usando [ASDF-VM](https://asdf-vm.com/)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).